# Different images are printed as same image using PrintVisual

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I'm using PrintDialog.PrintVisual() to print my viewmodel. For this I use binding on a dictionary:

```
<Canvas xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Width="329" Height="204">
    <Image Source="{Binding Details.Properties[Imagedata].ImageStream}" Stretch="Fill" Width="95" Height="122" Canvas.Left="14" Canvas.Top="41"/>
    <Image Source="{Binding Details.Properties[Signature].ImageStream}" Stretch="Fill" Height="25" Width="100" Canvas.Left="122" Canvas.Top="143"/>
</Canvas>
```

If I put this Canvas on my WPF window, it's showing fine. But if I want to print it, it's using the first image on my second image. In debugger I checked after UpdateLayout the Image.Source - both are right. The next step is `PrintDialog.Printvisual(canvas, "print");` The output is as described but not the same every time. Sometimes the first image is even repeated in the second `Image`.

Why does this happen?

**UPDATE**: I found a workaround: I search for all `Image` elements, copy the `ImageSource` into a `MemoryStream` and create a new `BitmapImage` out of it. It's not nice, but it works right now. If anybody could explain, why this works, it would be great.

Comment: Using threading somewhere in print operation?

Comment: Yes, we use come threads caused by architecture. Is there a way without avoiding threads?

Comment: I experienced a similar behavior but - strange enough - only when I test with XPS file printer. When I select my actual printer it works. Would be interested in any non-hack solution

Comment: @Matt, maybe the explanation you are looking for can be this by André Rocheleau here:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30523815/duplicate-images-printed-in-xps-file)